# How to acces some one's inbox with Application permission using MS Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

i want to use the Graph Api to access the o365 inbox to process the incoming mails.without user signed in ( Application permission) .

with that i can able to get the access token but i cant able to access the inbox. and the code as follows.

```
//Defining app
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
            .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
            .Build();


//Getting access token
result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
//graph service client
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new
DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);
            }));
//accessing Ms graph api 
var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages
                                .Request()
                                .Select(e => new {
                                    e.Sender,
                                    e.Subject
                                })
                                .GetAsync();
```

Code: BadRequest
Message: Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user.  Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.  Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps.

Inner error

I dont know what i am doing wrong here please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `.Me` since there is no authenticated user. You need to instead do something like:

```
//accessing Ms graph api 
var messages = await graphClient.Users["user-id"].Messages
                                .Request()
                                .Select(e => new {
                                    e.Sender,
                                    e.Subject
                                })
                                .GetAsync();
```

Where `user-id` is either the user's `id` from Graph, or their UPN (typically their email address).

Comment: This means still it is possible to read inbox mails from specified account whom need not to sign in/